# Read raw ethernet packet using python on Raspberry

Tags: python, linux, sockets, raspberry-pi, ethernet

I have a device which is sending packet with its own specific construction (header, data, crc) through its ethernet port.

What I would like to do is to communicate with this device using a Raspberry and Python 3.x.

I am already able to send Raw ethernet packet using the "socket" Library, I've checked with wireshark on my computer and everything seems to be transmitted as expected.

But now I would like to read incoming raw packet sent by the device and store it somewhere on my RPI to use it later.
I don't know how to use the "socket" Library to read raw packet (I mean layer 2 packet), I only find tutorials to read higher level packet like TCP/IP.

What I would like to do is Something similar to what wireshark does on my computer, that is to say read all raw packet going through the ethernet port.

Thanks,
Alban

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you please provide some Source Code and maybe some links to your research?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using ettercap package (ettercap-graphical)? 
It should be available with apt.

Alternatively you can try using TCPDump (Java tool) or even check ip tables